# How to assign return value from Json type object into TextBox but i am getting error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am calling a jquery function with ajax it will returned the FName,Lname,Address,Email on basic of specified id.
It returns the json type object when i am going to assign these values to TextBox ,Getting error.
so please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function BindGridView(id) {
  debugger;

        var params = "{ID:'" + id + "'}";
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "InsertoninGridViewusingJQuery.aspx/GetRecords",
          data: params,
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: "text",
          success: function (data) {
          alert(data.d.length);
         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
         debugger;

                $("#<%=txtFname.ClientID%>").val(data[i].FName);
                $("#<%=txtLname.ClientID%>").val(UserDetails.LName);
                $("#<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>").val(UserDetails.Address);
                $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").val(UserDetails.Email);

                 debugger;
             }
           }
          });
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Why you are using dataType as 'text' instead of 'json'?

Answer (score 1):

your `dataType` is text and your response is in json

try this

```
 dataType: "json",
```

and I think your success function should be

```
  success: function (data) {
      alert(data.d.length);


            $("#<%=txtFname.ClientID%>").val(data.FName);
            $("#<%=txtLname.ClientID%>").val(data.LName);
            $("#<%=txtAddress.ClientID%>").val(data.Address);
            $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>").val(data.Email);

             debugger;
         }
       }
```